# Dataframe column with subsequent matching value's index including range wrap-around direction from final index to initial index

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create Dataframe column(s) with the subsequent indexes for a certain value? I know I can find the matching indexes with

```
b_Index = df[df.Type=='B'].index
c_Index = df[df.Type=='C'].index
```

but I'm in need of a solution which includes the wrap-around case such that the 'next' index after the final match is the first index.

Say I have a dataframe with a `Type` series. `Type` includes values A, B or C.

```
d = dict(Type=['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'])
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
   Type
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     C
4     C
5     C
6     A
7     A
8     C
9     A
10    B
11    B
12    B
13    A
```

I'm looking to add `NextForwardBIndex` and `NextForwardCIndex` columns such that the result is

```
   Type  NextForwardBIndex  NextForwardCIndex
0     A                 10                  3
1     A                 10                  3
2     A                 10                  3
3     C                 10                  4
4     C                 10                  5
5     C                 10                  8
6     A                 10                  8
7     A                 10                  8
8     C                 10                  3
9     A                 10                  3
10    B                 11                  3
11    B                 12                  3
12    B                 10                  3
13    A                 10                  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit of [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), [`pandas.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), and [`pandas.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
# roll indices and assign the next values for B/C rows
df.loc[b_Index, 'NextForwardBIndex'] = np.roll(b_Index,-1)
df.loc[c_Index, 'NextForwardCIndex'] = np.roll(c_Index,-1)
# fill missing values
(df.ffill()
   .fillna({'NextForwardBIndex': b_Index[0],
            'NextForwardCIndex': c_Index[0]})
   .astype(int, errors='ignore')
)
```

output:

```
   Type  NextForwardBIndex  NextForwardCIndex
0     A                 10                  3
1     A                 10                  3
2     A                 10                  3
3     C                  4                  4
4     C                  5                  5
5     C                  8                  8
6     A                  8                  8
7     A                  8                  8
8     C                  3                  3
9     A                  3                  3
10    B                 11                  3
11    B                 12                  3
12    B                 10                  3
13    A                 10                  3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df2 = df['Type'].str.get_dummies().mul(s.index,axis=0).shift(-1).where(lambda x: x.ne(0)).bfill()

df2.fillna(df2.iloc[0]).rename('NextForward{}Index'.format,axis=1)
```

Old Answer:

```
(df.assign(NextForwardBIndex = df.loc[df['Type'].eq('B')].groupby(df['Type']).transform(lambda x: x.index.to_series().shift(-1)),
         NextForwardCIndex = df.loc[df['Type'].eq('C')].groupby(df['Type']).transform(lambda x: x.index.to_series().shift(-1)))
 .fillna({'NextForwardBIndex':df['Type'].eq('B').idxmax(),'NextForwardCIndex':df['Type'].eq('C').idxmax()}))
```

Output:

```
    NextForwardAIndex  NextForwardBIndex  NextForwardCIndex
0                 1.0               10.0                3.0
1                 2.0               10.0                3.0
2                 6.0               10.0                3.0
3                 6.0               10.0                4.0
4                 6.0               10.0                5.0
5                 6.0               10.0                8.0
6                 7.0               10.0                8.0
7                 9.0               10.0                8.0
8                 9.0               10.0                3.0
9                13.0               10.0                3.0
10               13.0               11.0                3.0
11               13.0               12.0                3.0
12               13.0               10.0                3.0
13                1.0               10.0                3.0
```